# Getting the value of a hidden input in coded ui

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I have a simple function to find elements on the page during the test by id as follows

```
    private UITestControl FindHtmlEditField(string keyToSearch)
    {
        HtmlEdit editFields = new HtmlEdit(_browserWindow);
        var matchedField = editFields.FindMatchingControls().FirstOrDefault(item => item.GetProperty(HtmlEdit.PropertyNames.Id).ToString().ToLower().Contains(keyToSearch.ToLower()));
        if (matchedField == null)
            throw new System.Exception(string.Format("Can't find {0} field", keyToSearch));

        return matchedField;
    }
```

If you change the control type to HtmlTextArea you can find the text area controls and also works with other types.

My question is if there is a chance to get a hidden input value. From the official list of classes https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.htmlcontrols.htmlcontrol.aspx there is none that could do.

Any ideas?

Comment: why can't you also find them by id? Hidden inputs are still part of the DOM.

Comment: @Crowcoder Correct, but CodedUi has its own mechanism to find the elements by setting the property SearchProperties. I haven't been able to find a combination which will give me the hidden input

Comment: It may be that you cannot directly access it. [Check this](http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/MVC/Post/Thread/4a3158f2-3119-4b36-ba40-751729e4dc43?category=vstest)